# How do I run OCR from a link to an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

I would like to run OCR on certain image links, for example this one: `https://i.redd.it/hsop5oo6rb351.jpg`. However, when trying to pass this link through this code:

```
def ocrImage(image):
  img = cv2.imread(image)
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  return text;
```

the console returns the error `TypeError: Unsupported Image Object`. I realize this refers to me trying to pass a link into a the `cv2.imread()` whose parameter is meant for a path; however, I can't find a way to convert my images to paths. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you not download the image and store it in the path of your choice? or does it have to be programmatically downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the image first and then pass it through the function to get OCR output.

```
import urllib.request
def ocrImage(URL):
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, "temp.jpg")
  img = cv2.imread("temp.jpg")
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  return text;
```

Comment: Since the image can be big, it might be a good idea to wait 2-3 sec before you call cv2.imread. Delay can be achieved using time.sleep(3)

Comment: it returns: ```Permission Error: [WinError 5] Access is denied.```

Comment: That must be because of the access issue on the folder where your code is running. You do not have access to save the image there.